# Graph OHLC with mplf in python 3

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to create a OHCL graph using matplotlibfinance, pandas, python 3 and this data:

```
                                Open       High        Low      Close     Volume
Date                                                                            
2020-02-27 01:51:00+00:00  167761.49  178565.38  165000.01  168764.01  358.79390
2020-02-27 01:52:00+00:00  167643.05  178565.38  165000.01  168764.01  357.62323
2020-02-27 01:53:00+00:00  167639.96  178565.38  165000.01  168896.91  357.71302
2020-02-27 01:54:00+00:00  168423.43  178565.38  165000.01  168765.00  359.22871
2020-02-27 01:55:01+00:00  168831.25  178565.38  165000.01  168101.24  359.35889
2020-02-27 01:56:01+00:00  168764.01  178565.38  165000.01  168199.29  359.54008
2020-02-27 01:57:01+00:00  168764.01  178565.38  165000.01  168199.29  359.75988
2020-02-27 01:58:01+00:00  168896.91  178565.38  165000.01  168199.29  359.82773
2020-02-27 01:59:02+00:00  168765.00  178565.38  165000.01  167630.31  359.94140
2020-02-27 02:00:02+00:00  168101.24  178565.38  165000.01  167962.76  359.50242
2020-02-27 02:01:02+00:00  168199.29  178560.31  165000.01  167962.76  358.84570
2020-02-27 02:02:03+00:00  168199.29  178560.31  165000.01  167977.55  358.80395
2020-02-27 02:03:03+00:00  168199.29  178560.31  165000.01  168063.80  358.79771
2020-02-27 02:04:02+00:00  167630.31  178560.31  165000.01  167833.41  358.51673
2020-02-27 02:05:03+00:00  167962.76  178560.31  165000.01  167833.41  358.46845
2020-02-27 02:06:04+00:00  167962.76  178560.31  165000.01  167891.95  358.38835
2020-02-27 02:07:03+00:00  167977.55  178560.31  165000.01  167805.38  358.37288
2020-02-27 02:08:04+00:00  168063.80  178198.74  165000.01  167806.28  357.97818
2020-02-27 02:09:04+00:00  167833.41  178198.74  165000.01  168980.93  357.86681
```

The code i wrote is the next one:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplfinance as mpf
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('Data/btc_mxnCopiaReorderedF.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
data.index.name='Date'
mpf.plot(dataf, type='candlestick', volume=True, figscale=2.0)
plt.savefig('Images/test0.png)
```

and as output I got is this image:
[image]

The image doesn't look like the typical OHCL graph, so the question is:
**Where is the mistake? In the code or in the data? If is in the data there is a way to manipulate the graph to look better?**

What I'm looking for is something like this:
[image: text]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plot is correct for your data.

Running describe() on your dataframe gives:

```
data.describe().loc[['mean','std','min','max']]
```

[image]

**Notice how small the Standard Deviations (std) are relative your values, especially for the low.**

**Your data is not changing much.  The High and the Low are significantly above and below the Open and the Close.  The plot is correct.**

Where did you get your data?  It could be that your columns are mislabled and/or some columns are actually missing.  What is the data supposed to be (ie. are they for a known stock)?

---

---

### OK.  I took **[the data you posted to pastebin](https://pastebin.com/aiU68Gt3)** and I wrote some code to resample the data and calculate a 30 minute Open, High, Low, Close from the `last` column.  **[You can see the code here](https://github.com/DanielGoldfarb/stackoverflow_60982755/blob/master/stackoverflow_60982755.ipynb)**.

And the plot looks like this:

[image: mplfinance.plot()]

I hope that helps.

Comment: I got the data from the Bitso exchange (https://bitso.com/api_info#ticker). The data frame here is not the raw data from the exchange ticker. I got the Close values by subtracting the last price and the last price from 5 entries before to get a 5 mins candles. There are also some columns that I omitted. These are all the columns they provide: book, volume, high, last, low, vwap, ask, bid, created_at.

Comment: @JesúsM.CarrilloM ... if you want to send me the file with the raw data, I will take a look at it, and see what I can determine.  Not sure what you mean about "5 mins candles" because the data you posted above are 1 minute ohlc points.

Comment: How can I send you the data? Here's the raw data corresponding a 1 day of logs, https://pastebin.com/aiU68Gt3 .

Comment: pastebin is fine.  I have the data.   I was looking on Bitso at JSON Response Payload definition.  The high and the low are for a 24 hour period.  It is not correct to plot them as the high and low of minute-by-minute candles.  Take only these columns: `last` and `volume` and `created_at`.  Take 5 rows at a time.  For each group of 5 rows make the 1st `last` the Open, the 5th `last` the Close, the maximum `last` High, and the min `last` the Low.  Sum the Volumes.  Now you have a 5 minute OHLCV row.  Use the last (5th row) `created_at` as the time stamp for that 5 minute row.

Comment: The data set (from pastebin) has so much data, I found that 5 minute interals were too small.  The candles were to close together to really see.  So I tried 30 minute intervals.  5 minute intervals can look ok if you then only plot maybe 4 to 8 hours worth of data (not the 24 hours of data in the data set).

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much.